# html listboxfor value cannot be null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework and I have a many to many relationship between Products and Categories.  I have created my models and they seemed to have created the tables correctly.  Now I am trying to insert a product and am getting the error: "Value cannot be null." on the line: `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.ProductCategories, Model.CategorySelectList.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Text, Value = c.Value }), new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose categorie(s)..."})`

Here is my ProductModel:

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Index("ItemNumber", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Item #")]
    public int itemNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public String product { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public String description { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    [Display(Name = "Active?")]
    public bool active { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Image Name")]
    public String imageName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PDF Name")]
    public String PDFName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category(s)")]
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryModel> ProductCategories { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategorySelectList { get; set; }

    //public ICollection<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }

    public virtual BrochureModel Brochure { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BrochureList { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getCategories(int id = 0)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {
            List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
            foreach (var cat in categories)
            {
                SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem { Value = cat.ID.ToString(), Text = cat.categoryName };

                if (id > 0 && cat.ID == id)
                {
                    sli.Selected = true;
                }
                list.Add(sli);
            }
            return list;
        }

    }

    public ProductModel()
    {
        active = true;
    }

}
```

Here is the method in the controller that populates the lists:

```
public ActionResult ControlPanel()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"] == null ? "" : TempData["Message"].ToString();

        //using (var db = new ProductContext())
        //{
        //    var categories = from c in db.Categories
        //                   select c;
        //    categories = categories.OrderByDescending(c => c.isActive);
        //    var model = new AdminModel
        //    {
        //        Categories = categories.ToList(),
        //        Products = db.Products.ToList(),
        //        RegisterUsers = db.RegisterViewModels.ToList()
        //    };

        //    return View(model);
        //}

        var model = new AdminModel();
        using (var db = new ProductContext())
        {
            var categories = from c in db.Categories
                             select c;
            categories = categories.OrderByDescending(c => c.isActive);
            model.Categories = categories.ToList();
            model.Products = db.Products.ToList();
            model.Brochures = db.Brochures.ToList();

        };
```

I probably have something wrong in the ListBoxFor line and maybe something wrong in my model too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: how does your controller populate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property `model.ProductCategories` is `ICollection<CategoryModel>`. You cannot bind a `<select multiple>` to a collection of complex objects, only a collection of value types. Assuming `Category.ID` is typeof `int` then your model needs a property (say)

```
public int[] SelectedCategories { get; set; } // or List<int>
```

and then in the view

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedCategories, Model.CategorySelectList, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose categorie(s)..."})
```

In you POST method, `SelectedCategories` will then contain the selected category ID's.

Note also `Model.CategorySelectList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so creating a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from it (as you are doing with `.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Text, Value = c.Value })` is just pointless extra overhead.

In addition the following code in your `getCategories()` method is also pointless.

```
if (id > 0 && cat.ID == id) { sli.Selected = true; }
```

Since your strongly binding to a model property, its the value of the property your binding to which determines which options will be selected and the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is simply ignored. If you want to pre-select options, then set the value of `SelectedCategories` in the controller. For example if `model.SelectedCategories = new int[] { 1, 3 }` and your options have values 1 to 10, then the 1st and 3rd options will be selected.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Can I ask one more question: how do I list out the categories in a different section of my view?  I keep getting the error: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: This is what I tried: `<span class="bold">Category:</span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCategories.ToString())`

Comment: Also, do I need get `SelectedCategories` added into my Products table?  When I try and run `ToList()` on my Products, it is complaining that the column `SelectedCategories` dos not exist.

Comment: The error occurs because you call `.ToString()` on the property (which is a method and the helpers can only use property accessors). With out seeing more code its impossible to resolve your issue so you really need to ask a new question showing the relevant code you have tried and the errors you getting